# How to export rows and columns to (CSV file 2) from a downloadable CSV hyperlink in (CSV file 1)

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, excel-formula, vlookup

3 csv files.

File 1:

[image]

File 2:

[image]

File 3(the file that can be downloaded by clicking on the link in File 1): [image]

My question is how do I formulate the excel so that it auto grabs the rows and columns in File 3 which can be downloaded with the link in File 1 and export the rows and columns in one line in a single cell in File 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to pre-process File 3 in VBA in Excel to concatenate the columns into a string.  ie:

```
temp_row = 2
temp_string = ""
while range("A" & temp_row) <> ""
   temp_string = temp_string & concatenate(Range("A" & temp_row), Range("B" & temp_row), Range("C" & temp_row))
   temp_row = temp_row + 1
wend
```